# Apache CustomLog help required

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to log images to a seperate file on the server for all domains.

This works:

```
CustomLog logs/host1-access-log combined env=!image
CustomLog logs/image-access-log combined env=image
```

But it is necessary to add this to each and every vhost. This quickly becomes a problem when you have 24710 hosts.

I don't have them :) but is it possible to get by with a single Customlog directive since all images are logged in the same file?

Apache 2.2.2

Thanks!

Maria

Answer (score 0):

According to my own personal experience (and the [mod_log page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog)), you can declare this at a global scale (i.e., the server config).  So outside of your VirtualHost, you can use:

```
CustomLog logs/host1-access-log combined env=!image
CustomLog logs/image-access-log combined env=image
<VirtualHost ...>
```

This will then apply to all VirtualHosts, unless they specifically override it.  Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: I was able to successfully accomplish this using the following config (listening on ports 81 and 82, for testing):

```
Listen 81
Listen 82

SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.gif$" image
CustomLog logs/image-access-log combined env=image

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName test81
    DocumentRoot /home/apache/test81
    CustomLog logs/host1-access-log combined env=!image
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:82>
    ServerName test82
    DocumentRoot /home/apache/test82
    CustomLog logs/host1-access-log combined env=!image
</VirtualHost>
```

The output from the log files is as follows (notice the double output to `access_log` and `host1-access-log`)

```
==> /var/log/httpd/image-access-log <==
10.1.2.239 - - [12/Sep/2010:13:23:34 -0400] "GET /image_on_81.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9"
10.1.2.239 - - [12/Sep/2010:13:23:42 -0400] "GET /image_on_81.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9"
10.1.2.239 - - [12/Sep/2010:13:23:48 -0400] "GET /image_on_82.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9"

==> /var/log/httpd/host1-access-log <==
10.1.2.239 - - [12/Sep/2010:13:23:57 -0400] "GET /not_an_image.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9"

==> /var/log/httpd/access_log <==
10.1.2.239 - - [12/Sep/2010:13:23:57 -0400] "GET /not_an_image.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9"
```

If you're still unable to achieve the desired effect, it may be that there may be other problems areas in your Apache config; if you post that as well, I'm sure I (or someone else) can help further. :)

Comment: I didn't see any option on mod_log page that this is inherited. This doesn't work. If I don't have the image entries inside virtualhost, image requests are not logged.

Comment: I was able to run this successfully with the desired results from Apache 2.2; so while my post does answer your question, it sounds like you have other issues in your Apache config.  Post configs to get more details!

Comment: This is not the answer i am looking for. I need CustomLogs inside each vhost because they all have seperate log files. If I specify a single Customlog with negation inside vhost, image entries are not being logged to the main server image log file. My config is fine. Thanks for trying to assist :)

Comment: BTW, what exactly is access_log there? There is no reference to it, so I am assuming it is specified with TransferLog. TransferLog does not support SetEnvIf assignments. That is why I have to use 2 CustomLogs inside vhosts. Before they were using just a single TransferLog.

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have copied your config directly; take another look at it and see if that's what you're getting at.  Currently, it will store ALL items marked with the "image" variable to a single logfile, while anything NOT marked will be sent to a host-specific file.  If this isn't what you're looking for, please update your question! :)

Comment: Redmumba, I had this same config before and it did not work. Is this working for you? It just doesnt log images for me like this.

Comment: Are you sure there's not another CustomLog floating around (possibly in your httpd.conf) that's superseding your own CustomLog?